# Change attributes of all files and folders in a given directory in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, basic

In visual Basic (Visual Studio), How do I change attributes of all files and folders in a directory that user choose using FolderBrowserDialog?

Heres my code to take input:

```
If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            RichTextBox1.Clear()
            Label1.Text = ""
            Dim initialFolder As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    RichTextBox1.Text = initialFolder
```

Now how do i use the variable inialFolder to change attribute of all files and folders in the directory/location stored in inialfolder?

Comment: One at a time.  Use DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() to enumerate the files, recurse with DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories() to hit the subdirs.

Comment: You should split your problem into smaller ones. Can you change the property of one file? Can you browse the files in a folder? Are you able to find all sub folders?